# How to make a C++ function that can process variable arguments and variable types?

Tags: c++

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
  class A
    {
      public:
         void process(int a, int b, int c)
         {
             std::cout<< "int a"<<a<<std::endl;
             std::cout<< "int b"<<b<<std::endl;
             std::cout<< "int c"<<c<<std::endl;
         }
     };
    class B
    {
      public:
         void process(double a)
         {
             std::cout<< "double a"<<a<<std::endl;

         }
     };
 struct ABC
 {
      float def;

   };
 class C
    {
      public:
         void process(ABC a)
         {
             std::cout<< "float def in ABC"<<a.def<<std::endl;

         }
     };
```

As you can see from the above examples, `class A, class B and Class C` share the same function `process`, which is used to print the all the arguments within the function. However, not only the number of the arguments may vary but also the type of the arguments. The arguments may be a primary C++ type, and it can be also a complex class defined by the user. In this case, how can I make a general function `process` that can be called by `class A, class B and Class C`.

Comment: This might help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: What would this general function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of arguments not fixed, different types:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename... T>
void func(T... t) {
    int arr[] = { (std::cout << t << std::endl, 0)... };
}

int main() { func(1, .42, "foo"); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use scope resolution operator to use the process function in main function like this

first declare the object the 
A::object_name.processs();

Comment: That does not answer OP's question, and your code is wrong.